# how to set equal width for all cells in excel sheet using vba

Tags: excel

I am populating the data from MS Access To Excel using VBA. During the population of the Excel sheet it automatically sets random widths for the columns. Is it possible to set width equally for all cells using VBA?

Comment: its really easy question... Have you tried to record that?

Answer (score 6):

```
Cells.RowHeight = 30
Cells.ColumnWidth = 10
```

Comment: Thank you but i wants to set the equal space for all the cells in the sheet i got the answer 
 ActiveSheetname.Columns.ColumnWidth = 12

Comment: This works exactly the same. "Cells" reflects all the cells in the worksheet. And I believe you meant ActiveSheet not ActiveSheetname

Comment: The defaults for a new sheet are `Cells.ColumnWidth = 8.49` and `Cells.RowHeight = 15`